# SharePoint 2013 Custom List / Document Library - Search Box

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, search, permissions, library

I have encountered a strange issue with the SP2013 search box.

I have a series of custom lists and document libraries on the same site. The majority of them are open access to all of my colleagues (via a 'contribute' permission level group and the use of the 'everyone' profile within this group). On all of these lists/libraries the search box works perfectly for all colleagues (i.e. at both 'contribute' level and super-user level)

However, on a handful of lists/libraries that include specific colleague names in the 'contribute' group (because the content is more confidential), the search box only works for the super-users. Colleagues in the 'contribute' group see the 'there is nothing to display' message when searching - even though there clearly is data to display!

I hope my explanation makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: Do you have break inheritance of the Lists that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Please go list settings>Permission for this list, have a check if list has unique permission and the contribute user group has proper permission(at least read) in these lists/libraries

If you have a button saying "delete unique permission" on the left top, it means there are unique permission in that list, use the check permission function to determine the permission of the contribute group in this list.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry. Thanks for replying. Much appreciated. The lists and libraries that are affected do have disinherited permissions, but the contribute group does have contribute permission on them. So I don't think this is the issue. Also, the other lists and libraries that the search is working fine on (where the 'everyone' profile is being used) also have disinherited permissions. The issue appears to be a result of there being specific names in the affected contribute group, rather than the 'everyone' profile? I'm completely stumped as to how to fix it !